# Access Imports statement triggers compilation error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to use an Imports statement in some Visual Basic code I want to use for calculations in an Access Database. Using this Statement, a compilation error is triggered each time. I also get this error message using this minimal example:

Table: "Testtable"

```
ID  | Test
----+-----
1   | a
2   | b
3   | c
4   | d
5   | e
```

Query: "SomeQuery"

```
SELECT foo() FROM Testtable WHERE ID=4;
```

Macro "bar" with function "foo":

```
Option Compare Database
Imports System.Data.SqlConnection

Public Function foo() As Integer
    foo = 42
End Function
```

As soon as I comment out the Import statement, it works again. Who knows how to fix it?

Comment: There's no such thing as an `Imports` statement in Access VBA. That's a VB.Net statement, and will never work in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up VBA versus VB.Net, and user-defined functions in Access versus those in SQL Server.

With Access and VBA, you can immediately use any publicly-defined function in a normal module in SQL. There's no need for `Imports System.Data.SqlConnection`. Unfortunately, these functions are limited to SQL statements that are executed using the Access application (e.g. doesn't work for ODBC or OLEDB connections), and you can't work around that.

`Imports` is a VB.Net keyword, which doesn't work in VBA. You can't work around that limitation.

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` is used for connecting to SQL server databases, and completely unrelated to Access.

So, if it works if you comment it out, then leave it commented out. Or even better: remove it altogether.

Comment: I see. Still I need to get some data from another table using this Access script. Have you got a suggestion how to do so?

Comment: Use DAO and recordsets. DAO is native to Access, and you can easily query other tables with it. You don't even need to add a reference to an external library.